# Confusing Firefox CSS Issue

Tags: css, firefox

Just noticed a strange problem with page rendering in firefox, and wondering if anybody can see the issue here obviously.

I'm sorry its a bit of a needle in a hay stack situation, but all I've got is the url of the site and css to give you!

http://nitrous-networks.co.uk/webdev/ the css is here
http://nitrous-networks.co.uk/webdev/css/style.css

If you load in chrome, safari, opera its fine, but firefox renders the middle content box half way across the screen! If you view it in a different browser you'll see how it meant to be displayed, then view in firefox and you'll notice the difference!!

So any light you could shed on this exact matter it would be appreciated!

**Progress Update:**
on line 489 of the CSS i found a stray " before the closing }. Once I removed this the styles applied correctly, However the positioning of my ul.homepage is still off screen.

Comment: Include the relevant code in your post. The source code at the links may change, which causes this question to be useless for future visitors.

Comment: Might wanna fix all the errors the W3 validator found: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fnitrous-networks.co.uk%2Fwebdev%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Why does `#main-content` have `min-height:100px`, while `.homepage` which is a direct child has `min-height:500px`? This could be optimized.

Comment: You seem to have a larger CSS issue. Open your page in IE9 (which has good CSS support) and you'll notice that the first and third box have presentation issues (which are similar to the ones in Firefox).

Comment: @RobW Sorry I've no idea what the relevant code is as I dont know where the problem is. @ j08691 - all completely irrelevant errors there. @ Sime Vidas no idea, different days, different code, changed now. @ Sime Vidas again - my IE is broken so i'll try fix it to see what you mean. @ sg3s I thought this place was to help others not boost egos- i always say thank you to the correct answer.

Comment: What exact version of Firefox? Firefox 12 renders identically to Chrome.

Comment: @MaratTanalin hi, 10.0.2 is the versions we're testing in. Should I be worried about that version?

Comment: @OwenMelbourne: Of course, Firefox 10 is recent enough to deserve to be taken into account. I'd recommend you to create a _minimal_ testcase sothat people could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to omit the `overflow:hidden` on line 482 in styles.css... I don't know why, but it looks a bit better...

Comment: thankyou for a half useful reply! is there a possibility that firefox only renders stuff that are visible? so I should apply overflow:hidden once the page has loaded?

Comment: I personally don't like doing such work-arounds with JavaScript because you will lose overview. And I doubt that it would help, but again, I don't know exactly, the browsers sometimes seem to be unpredictable and the best way is to try everything out. Firebug helps you a lot doing this.

Answer (score 0):

still could not figure out why exactly firefox was rendering the div 960px extra to the right, however I applied this fix temporarily

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() { div.homepage {left:-960px;}}
```

this would counter the extra added 960px in firefox only